# Is there any benefit to import the entire module before importing part of it?

Tags: webpack, angular

Currently I am studying the project [**angular2-webpack-starter**](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter). Its `webpack.config.js` has two entries: `main.ts` and `vendor.ts`.

main.ts

```
import {provide} from 'angular2/core';
import {bootstrap, ELEMENT_PROBE_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS, LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from 'angular2/router';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';

import {App} from './app/app';

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function main() {
  bootstrap(App, [
    ...('production' === process.env.ENV ? [] : ELEMENT_PROBE_PROVIDERS),
    ...HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    ...ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    provide(LocationStrategy, { useClass: HashLocationStrategy })
  ])
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
});
```

vendor.ts

```
// Polyfills
import 'es6-shim';
// (these modules are what are in 'angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills' so don't use that here)
import 'es6-promise';
import 'zone.js/lib/browser/zone-microtask';

if ('production' !== process.env.ENV) {
  // Reflect Polyfill
  require('es7-reflect-metadata/dist/browser');
  Error['stackTraceLimit'] = Infinity;
  Zone['longStackTraceZone'] = require('zone.js/lib/zones/long-stack-trace.js');
}

if ('production' === process.env.ENV) {
  // Reflect with es7-reflect-metadata/reflect-metadata is added
  // by webpack.prod.config ProvidePlugin
  let ngCore = require('angular2/core');
  ngCore.enableProdMode();
}
// Angular 2
import 'angular2/platform/browser';
import 'angular2/platform/common_dom';
import 'angular2/router';
import 'angular2/http';
import 'angular2/core';

// RxJS
import 'rxjs';
```

I understand the `vendor.js` is to import dependencies. But why are angular2 modules imported here? Since they are imported in other files (like `main.ts`) as well, it seems there is no necessity to import them twice or in advance.

Comment: To keep the dependency resolution isolated.

Comment: @binariedMe Could you explain in more details please?

Comment: Not much sure about my logic so I put as comment. But the use of importing same file in both main.ts and vendor.ts is that main.ts can be used in some other places as well where no other code are using that file.

Lets say main.ts is being imported in vendor.ts and vendor1.ts both. main.ts has one import angular2/angular2 , vendor.ts has one import angular2/angular2 and vendor1.ts has one import angular2/SomeOtherModule. 
Now angular2 of main.ts won't raise any conflict with SomeOtherModule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it. According to the webpack's code splitting article, in the [Split app and vendor code section](https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html#split-app-and-vendor-code) it is explained that all dependancies imported in the vendor file will be excluded from your main bundle.

> This will remove all modules in the vendor chunk from the app chunk. The bundle.js will now contain just your app code, without any of it’s dependencies. These are in vendor.bundle.js.

That way your bundle file will be more clean because all of the angular code and all of the other libraries code will be separated in another vendor file.